# Is Numeric or integer a valid JSON?

Tags: json

I tested putting just random integer value in a field during a laravel validation. It is returning it as a valid json. Then I tested it at https://jsonlint.com/?code= and that is also returning it as a valid JSON. I am a beginner so Can anyone please explain how it is a valid json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very early on, the definition of JSON was that it had to have an object or array at the top level, but that was quickly abandoned in favor of allowing any valid value at the top level. So all of these are valid JSON:

A number on its own:

```
42
```

A string on its own:

```
"question"
```

A boolean on its own:

```
false
```

An object:

```
{"answer": 42}
```

An array:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

More on [json.org](https://json.org) and [in the standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm).

Comment: *(It* had *to happen. If you note a missing `}` on the object above, hit refresh.)*